# UI Code in viewDidLayoutSubViews doesn't render correctly at runtime

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, viewdidappear, viewdidlayoutsubviews

I have recently been battling with my view controller to set the correct dimensions of a border on a `UIView`.

*edit, this is for a static tableview (i am using it as a form). I am aware of rounding cells in a .xib and reusing the cell however I am not reusing cells, this approach would not be useful to me.

I have a screen with a static tableview which is embedded within a `UIView` and displayed on a main `View Controller`. I had been having problems with the border as if I set it anywhere before `viewDidAppear` my method to add the border would use the wrong dimensions and display the border incorrectly. Here is the method I'm using to add a border to my UIView:

```
- (void)createCellBorder: (UIView *)view container:(UIView *)container {
    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];

    CGRect adjustedContainer = CGRectMake(0, 0, container.frame.size.width - 20, container.frame.size.height);

    CGRect borderFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, (adjustedContainer.size.width), (view.frame.size.height));
    NSLog(@"VIEW DIMENSIONS FOR %@ %f, %f",view , view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);
    [borderLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
    [borderLayer setFrame:borderFrame];
    [borderLayer setCornerRadius:view.frame.size.height / 2];
    [borderLayer setBorderWidth:1.0];
    [borderLayer setBorderColor:[kTextColor2 CGColor]];
    [view.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
}
```

Note * To fix some bugs with a single cell having the wrong dimensions (always the final cell in the table) I am setting the width of the border layer based on the `UITableView` it is contained in.

Anyway I eventually found out that instead of using `viewDidAppear` I should be using `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to set my UI Geometry as at this point in time the view has calculated its dimensions. This works a treat and my cells will display with rounded borders... However there is a problem with the rendering itself.

First lets have a look at the cells being rounded from the `viewDidAppear`.[image: cells rounded in the viewDidAppear]

Everything looks fine, this is exactly how I want my cells to look (I have removed the content of them to demonstrate the borders only). Lets have a look at the code I'm using to round the cells.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self configureCells];

}

- (void)configureCells {
    [self createCellBorder:_contentCellOne container:_profileTable];
    [self createCellBorder:_contentCellTwo container:_profileTable];
    [self createCellBorder:_contentCellThree container:_profileTable];
    [self createCellBorder:_contentCellFour container:_profileTable];
    [self createCellBorder:_contentCellFive container:_profileTable];
    [self createCellBorder:_contentCellSix container:_profileTable];
    [self createCellBorder:_contentCellSeven container:_profileTable];
}
```

Now lets change where I call `configureCells` from and see the difference.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self configureCells];

}
```

All that has changed is where I call this method from. And in theory this should be the right place to configure my UI (and certainly more optimal than calling from `viewDidAppear`).

[image: cells rounded in viewDidLayoutSubViews]

As you can see there is some quite noticeable 'distortion' around the corners of the cells. The pictures provided are from the simulator but I have tried this on a device and get the same result (maybe looks worse on my phone).

I have no idea why this is happening, and it means that whilst I have got my code out of the `viewDidAppear`, its just as unusable as before. I assume there will be a rendering option I can tweak in the `viewDidLayoutSubViews` but can't seem to find anything. All suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: Also worth noting, when the code is set from `viewDidLayoutSubViews` the apps performance suffers heavily.

Comment: Why don’t you add border in layoutSubviews method of cells?

Comment: why you are setting border for cell in viewDidAppear of your controller. you can try creating custom class for your cell and set border for your cell.

Comment: @NileshMahajan This is a static table view, I am not reusing cells I am creating custom ones (i brushed out the cell content). I have done this exact thing for dynamic table views in other sections of the app and everything works fine.

Comment: @trungduc This is a static table view, all of the cells are connected up via IB, I cannot use any tableview methods here unfortunately

Comment: you can still use custom class here. create new custom class from UITableViewCell and use that for every cell on IB. write your border code inside custom class.

Comment: @NileshMahajan I actually found a problem with my border code and now everything is fixed. The reason I wasn't initially using the border property for my view was because I was using `maskToBounds` so I had to essentially create an overlay layer. Since switching my code to use the built in border functions it seems to be working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should create a subclass for `UITableViewCell` and configure border of cells inside `layoutIfNeeded` method.

I have create a demo project, you can check it [TableViewCellBorder](https://github.com/trungducc/stackoverflow/tree/table-view-cell-border).

Comment: Yes this would be a great way of doing things with a dynamic table. I have infact done this very method in rounding some of the cells in a propper table view in my app. Unfortunately because I am using a static table view I cannot call any cell methods.

Comment: Ok so while my original question hasn't really been answered, I opened up your project and looked at how you were applying your border to the cells. I reworked your code into my border creation method and everything seemed to work much better.

The code can actually now be triggered in the `viewWillAppear` and all works as intended.. wierd! Thanks for the demo

Comment: Great :D. Happy coding friend!

Comment: You should configure the border in `-layoutSubviews` not `-layoutIfNeeded`.